# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in Radio Button alertDialog

Tags: java, android, radio-button, indexoutofboundsexception

I am developing an app for a survey service. 
The user must enter their country in order to sign up. 
I am using an `alertDialog` using `radio buttons`.

Here is my java code:

```
public void onClickCountrySCI(View view) {

    final String[] CategorySelected = {null};
    final String categories[] = {"USA", "Mexico", "Canada"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Country:");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(categories, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            CategorySelected[0] = categories[i];
        }

    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if (CategorySelected[0].equals("USA")) {

                et4.append(categories[i]);
            } else if (CategorySelected[1].equals("Mexico")) {

                et4.append(categories[i]);
            } else if (CategorySelected[2].equals("Canada")) {

                et4.append(categories[i]);
            }
        }

    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    }).create();
    builder.show();
}
```

I keep getting an error. It is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

How can I get rid of this? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** 
**UPDATED CODE**

```
public void onClickCountrySCI(View view) {
    final String[] CategorySelected ={""};
    final String categories[] = {"USA", "Mexico", "Canada"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Country:");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(categories, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            CategorySelected[0] = categories[i];
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (CategorySelected.equals("USA")) {
                et4.append(categories[i]);
            } else if (CategorySelected.equals("Mexico")) {
                et4.append(categories[i]);
            } else if (CategorySelected.equals("Canada")) {
                et4.append(categories[i]);
            }
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    }).create();
    builder.show();
}
```

Here is my updated code.

Here is my EditText XML:

```
<EditText
    android:onClick="onClickCountrySCI"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_fourteen_sci"
    android:id="@+id/et_fifteen_sci"
    android:hint="Country"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp" />
```

This is all my updated code.

I don't get errors no more, but the radio button values are being placed to the EditText.

Comment: Check how many data there . `[n]` ??

Comment: Here the problem with CategorySelected[] array. You have initialize with same size of categories[]. e.g.   final String[] CategorySelected = {null,null,null};

Comment: Instead of using array , you should be using simply string. Convert Category Selected from array to string

Comment: final String[] CategorySelected = {null}; initialize some default value

Comment: what do you think `CategorySelected[1]` does`?

Comment: Since your edit is so drastically changing your question (coming from an exception to working but not as you expect it) maybe you should open a new question and pinpoint there what is the issue left.

Answer (score 0):

try Changing this:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(categories, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            CategorySelected[0] = categories[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using String array you can use arrayList becasue you are not specifyng the size of the list before.

Instead of `final String[] CategorySelected = {null};` add  `ArrayList<String>mCategorySelected=new ArrayList<>();`

```
final String categories[] = {"USA", "Mexico", "Canada"};

DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        //Add to arraylist here

        mCategorySelected.add(i,categories[i]); 
    }

}).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        //check from arraylist here

        if (mCategorySelected.get(0).equals("USA")) {

            et4.append(categories[i]);
        } else if (mCategorySelected.get(1).equals("Mexico")) {

            et4.append(categories[i]);
        } else if (mCategorySelected.get(2).equals("Canada")) {

            et4.append(categories[i]);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:
Also if you dont want to change the code and keep String array then you have to change this `CategorySelected[0] = categories[i];` to `CategorySelected[i] = categories[i];` since each time you are adding to index 0.
Also make an intialize to the array like this  `final String[] CategorySelected = new String[4];`